# PHP - Difference Between 2 Dates in Days

Tags: php, date, datediff

I have the following:

```
$dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'startdate' , true);
$dateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $dateStart);
$dStart = $dateStart->format('d/m/y');true);
$dEnd = date("d/m/y");
echo $dStart .'-'.$dEnd;
```

This outputs `12/06/15-28/10/15` but for the life of me I can't work out how to get the difference in days between the two dates.

Any advice? I've tried a few things but they error out each time.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most secure way I found to compute the number of days between a date `DateTime $a` and another on `DateTime $b` is to rely on their timestamps at midnight:

```php
protected static function diffDays(DateTime $a, DateTime $b)
{        
   return round(
       ($a->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp() - $b->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp())
       / 86400 // 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400s in 24h
   ); 
}
```

Work very well for me :)

*Note:* I use hard coded value `86400` in order to reduce useless processing time calculating `60 * 60 * 24`

Answer (score 0):

***Use this(Working Example)***

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");

$dateStart = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'startdate' , true);
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $dateStart));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $dateStart)));

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$date_diff = $interval->format('%R%a days');

echo "Difference is ".$date_diff
```

Comment: can you comment the reason please??

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It's unfortunate that the asker isn't able to work with DateTime objects...

Comment: @MikelBitson thanx for hlps

Answer (score -1):

Use **DateTime::diff** - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$dateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $dateStart);
$dateEnd = new DateTime();
$difference = $dateStart->diff($dateEnd);
```

Also note that not passing the end to diff() will assume now. So this would work also, in your particular example:

```
$dateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $dateStart);
$difference = $dateStart->diff();
```

Comment: Sorry - no luck here with that

Comment: @pee2pee This is the proper way of doing it. Perhaps you could show me more of the code and elaborate on what you're trying to get from it? This will give you a timestamp of the difference, formatting options are available with $difference->format(). Perhaps read through the PHP documentation I provided?

Comment: I copied/pasted exactly what you posted but the page ends up blank

Comment: @pee2pee That sounds like the problem. Considering I didn't include 100% of your code from the first post, where did you paste it? The real purpose of stack is to gain understanding, not have people write the code for you- try to understand the datetime doc page I provided a link to?

Comment: I do try and have tried and do understand what you are trying to say but for whatever reason, its not working. I'd love to learn more but unfortunately time is against me on this piece of work

Answer (score -1):

```
$daysBefore = round(abs(strtotime(Date("l, d F Y"))-strtotime($dateStart))/86400);
$daysAfter =  round(abs(strtotime(Date("l, d F Y"))-strtotime($dateEnd))/86400);
```

This seemed to be the only way I could get it to work

Comment: Why would anyone mark the correct answer down? Strange.

Comment: ^ This is likely because it's incredibly difficult to read and understand, uses way too many function calls on one line, and doesn't use the (modern) industry standard for PHP dates (DateTime).